# Freemarker error when ?join on null field since changing SpringBoot dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, freemarker

**Solved**: the error was already there, I only assumed I recently created it...

---

I have a project where I'm using SpringMVC and Freemarker.
In my controller I add an attribute to the model named `activities` like this:

```
@GetMapping("/activities/{floorId}")
public String activities(Model model, @PathVariable String floorId) {
    model.addAttribute("activities", activityService.getActivitiesForFloor(floorId));
    return "floor/activities";
}
```

`activities` has a field called `involvedTiles` which sometimes is `null`. This is perfectly fine.
In my Freemarker view I use the modelattribute like this:

```
<#list activities as activity>
<tr>
    <td>${activity.id}</td>
    <td>${activity.involvedTiles?join(", ")}</td>
</tr>
</#list>
```

This has always worked (it never gave an error). But now I suddenly get this error:

```
2016-10-21 13:56:17,163 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] [DirectJDKLog.java:181] Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> activity.involvedTiles  [in template "floor/activities.ftl" at line 51, column 27]

----
Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it.
----
Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present#deleted-channelwhen-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??
----
...etc...
```

I understand I'm getting this error, because `activity.involvedTiles` is `null` and I try to use it with the `?join()` function. But I'm not understanding why this suddenly stopped working. The only thing I can think of is that I've updated my SpringBoot dependency from 1.3.0.RELEASE to 1.4.1.RELEASE. In SpringBoot 1.3.0 they use [org.freemarker 2.3.23](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions) and in SpringBoot 1.4.1 they use [org.freemarker 2.3.25-incubating](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions).
My question: did Freemarker change something and is that why I'm getting this error?

---

I checked the [site of freemarker 2.3.23](http://freemarker.org/docs/versions_2_3_23.html) and [freemarker 2.3.25](http://freemarker.org/docs/versions_2_3_25.html) but couldn't find something that explains this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?join` was never intended to tolerate a `null`, and there was no such bug (accidentally allowing `null`) either as far as I know. Also, I have tried this with FreeMarker 2.3.21 (a really old version) and it still doesn't allow `null` there.

Comment: You're right... I checked out an earlier revision and I saw that the error already existed there. This error lived unnoticed for several months until I found it today. I assumed this error was recently created, 'cause nobody came complaining to me about it. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you can loop this activities collection in controller level before you put that into model map. Within loop you can check the value of activity and value of activity.involvedTiles. If the values at controller side is printing you can confirm where is the bug. If value is null at there then you don't need to find about freemarker.

**How to handle null values in freemarker**
In freemarker you can handle null values like this.

```
    <td><#if activity.involvedTiles??>${activity.involvedTiles?join(", ")}</#if></td>
```

Full ftl file

```
<#list activities as activity>
<tr>
    <td>${activity.id}</td>
    <td><#if activity.involvedTiles??>${activity.involvedTiles?join(", ")}</#if></td>   
</tr>
</#list>
```

Comment: `activity.involvedTiles` can be `null`, see my edited question. This has never been a problem for the Freemarker code above. Only recently I got this error and that is why I'm asking this question.

Comment: In case you need to handle that `null`, and you just want to get an empty string in that case, then the above example with the `#if` is an overkill. It can simply be written as: `activity.involvedTiles!?join(", ")`; note the `!`.